# How can I get the projected distance between a line segment and a circle?

Tags: java, 2d, collision, axis, bullet

I am making a 2D shooting game in Java, I need to be able to work out the maximum distance a circle could travel forwards (Only on the Y-axis) and get the distance as a float value, I have looked everywhere and can only find the closest distance to the line, but I only want the forward distance. This image is an example of how I am trying to get it to work, the line is a wall and the circles are bullets. If someone could give me a simple Java function that would be brilliant. I need it to take into account the whole circumference of the circle, so even if it slightly clips the wall with the edge, I need that distance. If the line is above the circle I want it to return a negative value, if the line is below I want a positive value, and if they would not collide, return POSITIVE_INFITITY.

[image]

I have tried many different functions I have found online but none seem to suit my purpose of just using the Y axis distance.

Comment: They are bigger than just a point, they have a set radius of 10.

Comment: Yes I think I could work that out.

Comment: Imagine another wall parallel and below the one that stops the bullets. The distance between the walls on a line that intersects both walls at right angles is the radius of the bullets. The bullets behave as if they are point size, but stopped by the imagined wall.  So, you need to calculate the distance **g** between the walls along a *vertical* line that intersects both walls. The bullet is stopped when its center is **g** distance below the real wall.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm sorry, I got distracted shortly after this was posted.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the *[java.awt.geom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/package-summary.html)* *framework* contains helpful *math* functions.

The *[Line2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html)* class has the *[Line2D#ptLineDist](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptLineDist(double,double,double,double,double,double))* method, for calculating this distance, without the radius.

For that, I imagine you're calculating a different angle for the bullet.
This is at least a resource, for that solution.

```java
double a = Line2D.ptLineDist(20, 40, 100, 10, 40, 100);
double b = Line2D.ptLineDist(20, 40, 100, 10, 65, 100);
System.out.printf("a = %s, b = %s", a, b);
```

Output

```
a = 63.202219485910504, b = 71.9803055256203
```

Comment: Yes, the O/P is calculating a different angle for the bullet.  Although `Line2D#ptLineDist` was not specifically mentioned, the O/P did say he / she found how to do this caclulation, and that is not what is wanted.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, if the radius is _10_, just use _30, 90_ and _50, 110_, etc..